# AngularJS share data between components

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please see this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yeYx6qEOjCLnd2XXZjN0?p=preview)

There are two components. component1 and common. I want to share data between those two components. In `component1.post` module, I created a service `messages`.

```
// service
angular.module('component1.post').factory('messages', function(sharetexts) {
  const messages = {};

  messages.userInput = sharetexts.userInput;

  messages.changeInput = function(text) {
    sharetexts.change(text);
  };

  return messages;
});
```

In `common.sharedata` module

```
angular.module('common.sharedata', []);

angular.module('common.sharedata').factory('sharetexts', function() {
  const sharetexts = {};

  sharetexts.userInput = 'User Input';

  sharetexts.change = function(text){
    console.log('Service is called.');
    sharetexts.userInput = text;
    console.log(sharetexts);
  }

  return sharetexts;
});
```

The problem is in the `component1.post` module, when I input a new text, i can see the `userInput` changed in `common.sharedata`. **But in module `component1.list`, `{{list.userInput}}` does not change.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because string is not reference type, but value type.
You cannot pass string, because it will be just copied, not referenced.

```
messages.userInput = sharetexts.userInput;
```

Here you just creating new string, not reference to it.

Check this plnkr

https://plnkr.co/edit/rR6MB9QDGCIiYYJ7i1CL?p=preview